# How to Migrate and Configure Sharepoint Databases from TFS 2015 Production to TFS SandBox Server

Tags: sharepoint-2010, tfs-2015

Currently in my company i have 2 TFS 2015 Environments (Production and Sandbox Servers). I am trying to restore Sharepoint databases from Tfs Production database to SandBox Servers and completed. But i dont know how to configure those sharepoint databases on Team Foundation Sever Admin Console and how i can see all the websites and documents which i migrated from tfs production in TFS Sandbox Server aswell.

Configuration:

TFS 2015 and Sharepoint 2010

If any one have any idea could you please help me to configure on admin console.

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following steps to migrate the sharepoint databases:

1. Install the Sharepoint and the TFS extensions on the sandbox server.
2. Remove the WSS_Content database on the sandbox server.
   For the above two steps, you could refer to this [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/install/sharepoint/move-sharepoint-new-hardware#detach-the-sharepoint-content-database).
3. Backup the WSS_Content database on the Production server.
4. Restore the WSS_Content database on the sandbox server.
5. Re-configure the sharepoint server via the command line.
   For the above three steps, you could refer to this [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/upgrade-2013/backup-and-restore-data).

Comment: @Raj Have you resolved your issue by above solution? any update?